# Altering the SQL Username

Tags: sql, sql-server

An example of changing the username is

```
ALTER USER Mary5 WITH NAME = Mary51;
```

(from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
)

However that requires special permission.

I am looking for a way to change the username from only having the username and password of the same simple user of whom I want to change

such as

```
ALTER LOGIN ALogin WITH PASSWORD = 'Se6ure?' OLD_PASSWORD = '2Secr@s';
```

which is an example from https://sqlity.net/en/2322/change-password/.
This means the user themselves can alter their own password without any special permission, I want the same but for usernames.

(I used this as `ALTER USER AUser WITH PASSWORD = 'Se6ure?' OLD_PASSWORD = '2Secr@s';` because I'm only altering users, not logins)

So overall, is there any way of altering a username of a user given you have the password and username of the same user and that user hasn't been granted any special permissions?

Comment: Sure you can use [EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Yes and no. No, users themselves won't be able to do this, it's a security risk -- I could attempt to change my name to an account to guess if it exists, bypassing restrictions on that, or I could change my name to a misleading one, like `superAdmin`. Yes, you can create a stored procedure that uses `EXECUTE AS sa` with the sole function of changing names, and give regular users permission to execute it. But, due to the above security concerns, you may not wish to do that.

Comment: This sounds a bit like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why do you want to a user to be able to change their username in the first place? Seems like the problem you're trying to solve is that you want users to be able to change their username, when in fact the problem might be far more simple (maybe orphaned users?)

Comment: Is your intent to change only the username? How is the password relevent? Is this to be done for the currently logged in user or by a user that will change the name for other users?

Comment: @DanGuzman My intent is to only change the username of a currently logged in account. The password part I mentioned is relevant in the way that you can change your password without needing any special permission, I am looking for a way to replicate that but for the username instead.

Comment: @Larnu I am attempting to use an SQL database for a project, I can't find a way to allow users without any access to create appropriate accounts freely so the idea is to create and use a batch of users with their roles and permissions already assigned, then I would use a program to grab one of the accounts and change the password and username to one that the user wants. E.g. A user wants YellowCircle as username and Pa33w0rd as the password, the program will then grab an account from the batch and alter the username and password to match the given one, then give them that account.

Comment: Why does the user care what their username is for a **SQL Database**? I might use the DisplayName `Larnu` on Stack Overflow, but if my username in the database is `'u1282371630981760'` I don't care. Why do they? If the user needs access, then the DBA should be creating them a user and doing the permissions; not the user themselves. That's a **huge** security concern.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for that, it is the solution to my situation. For my own case those security concerns pose no risk so I should be fine.

Comment: @Larnu It is a security concern, however it's purely for a private project and I'm just trying to get something working.

Comment: I still don't actually see what it is you're trying to get working though. The *real* problem here isn't the (in)ability of the user to be able to change their username.

Comment: If you really want users to "create accounts freely", it makes little sense to give them accounts by taking these from some pool that are then renamed. You can either make them all members of a Windows group and give that group permissions (if using integrated authentication) so no account management is necessary at all or, if you really want people to be able to create SQL logins at will, use a dedicated account with a well-known password people can login with (`UserCreator`) that has permission to do one thing, which is to call a `CreateUser` stored procedure that does the deed.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am going to do what you said because it is a better idea (the UserCreator part in my case). Thanks.